# Excel selecting special condition

Tags: excel, select

I have two types of data. All the data is located in cells A1:A136044 How it is possible to select only second variants? Some cell data ends with "2000", "Some word" or "\". I need to select these rows. However all the rows that are ending with ".pdf", ".xls" or ".whatever" does not need to be selected. Is there anything built in solution? Can't find anything useful in Excel itself.

After selection I will delete rows with Home -> Cells -> Delete -> Delete Sheet Rows

```
C:\Reports\Point\Germany\                            (select this one)
C:\Reports\Point\Germany\Berlin                      (select this one)
C:\Reports\Point\Germany\Berlin\2005                 (select this one)
C:\Reports\Point\Germany\Berlin\2005                 (select this one)
C:\Reports\Point\Germany\Berlin\2016\filename.pdf 
C:\Reports\Point\Germany\Berlin\2016\filename.docx
C:\Reports\Point\Germany\Berlin\2016\filename.whatever
```

Comment: It is not possible unless you specify a **full comprehensive** list of the file extensions. `.Nine` is otherwise indistinguishable from `.pdf`.

Comment: True.. then I have to use suggested previously option and hope there are no dots in Folder names.

Comment: ...and hope there are no files without an extension :)

Comment: Or, if you can influence **how the Excel sheet is created** you may want each folder name to end with ` \ ` and - voila!

Comment: Well, this is quite XY question. I have created my list with `C:\>dir /s /b>filelist.txt` because my VBA code took more than 12 hours to run through 120000+ files on server so I just gave up with straight to Excel VBA code idea. However I would need to list only files and not folders at all.

Comment: Since you only need the folders, I think `C:\>dir /s /a:d /b>filelist` will do.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but as I have mentioned earlier only files, no folders at all.

Comment: As you correctly noticed, it's an illustrative instance of the XY problem. **Forget the Excel** and find rather how to list all the files *outside* of Excel.

Comment: Should I delete my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will select any text that doesn't have an extension on the end.

So paths like `C:\Reports\Point\Germany\Berlin\.pdf` and `C:\Reports\Point\Germany\Berlin\20.05` have an extension, while `C:\Reports\Point\Germany\Berlin.2005\2005` doesn't.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rPaths As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim ext As String
    Dim rSelection As Range

    Set rPaths = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A8") 'Update to your range.
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    For Each rCell In rPaths
        ext = FSO.GetExtensionName(rCell)

        'Just place word "Select" one cell to right of "selected" cell.
        If ext = "" Then rCell.Offset(, 1) = "Select"

        'Select the cells.
        If ext = "" Then
            If rSelection Is Nothing Then
                Set rSelection = rCell
            Else
                Set rSelection = Union(rSelection, rCell)
            End If

            rSelection.Select
        End If

    Next rCell

End Sub
```